# Uploading multiple files in one request Dropzone Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, dropzone.js

I am using DotNet Core 2 MVC for my web application with Dropzone 4.3

I am trying to upload multiple files, my controller is receiving nothing.

Here is my JS code:

```js
    Dropzone.options.uploader = {
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 10, // MB
        url: '/Home/Upload',
        acceptedFiles: ".txt,.pc1",
        method: "Post",
        //autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        clickable: true,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        createImageThumbnails: true,

        accept: function (file, done,response) {
            if (file.name == "test.jpg") {
                alert("Can't upload a test file.");
            }
            else {
                //Show a confirm alert and display the image on the page.
   
                done(); 
                

            }
        }


    };
```

My html code :

```html
<div id="dropzone">
     <form   class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" id="uploader"enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                  Drop files here or click to upload.<br>
           </div>
     </form>                              
</div>
```

My controller action method :

```
 [![Screenshot of Action Method in Debug Mode][1]][1]
```

As you can see the action method is hit however no files are received.

when the action method is as below then multiple concurrent hits are done to the action method with file.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile file)
```

However I would want one request with multiple files collection.

Is this possible?

Also note when autoProcessQueue: false is present it is does not hit my action method.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
[Route("upload-files")]
[HttpPost]
public object UploadFiles()
{
    var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

    // response
}
```

Comment: Please add additional informatiosn to your answer. Do not just paste code.